# SQL Server insert with XML parameter - empty string not converting to null for numeric

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, insert

I have a stored procedure that takes an XML parameter and inserts the "Entity" nodes as records into a table.  This works fine unless one of the numeric fields has a value of empty string in the XML.  Then it throws an "error converting data type nvarchar to numeric" error.

Is there a way for me to tell SQL to convert empty string to null for those numeric fields in the code below?

```
-- @importData XML <- stored procedure param
DECLARE @l_index INT

EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @l_index OUTPUT, @importData
INSERT INTO dbo.myTable
(
     [field1]
    ,[field2]
    ,[field3]
)
SELECT
     [field1]
    ,[field2]
    ,[field3]
FROM OPENXML(@l_index, 'Entities/Entity', 1)
    WITH 
    (
         field1 int 'field1'
        ,field2 varchar(40) 'field2'
        ,field3 decimal(15, 2) 'field3'
    )
EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @l_index
```

EDIT: And if it helps, sample XML.  Error is thrown unless I comment out field3 in the code above or provide a value in field3 below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Entities>
  <Entity>
    <field1>2435</field1>
    <field2>843257-3242</field2>
    <field3 />
  </Entity>
</Entities>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would use SQL Server XQuery, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT
   nodes.entity.value('(field1)[1]', 'int') 'Field1',
   nodes.entity.value('(field2)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Field 2',
   CAST(ISNULL(nodes.entity.value('(field3)[1]', 'varchar(50)'), '0.00') 
        AS DECIMAL(15,2)) 'Field 3'
FROM
   @importData.nodes('/Entities/Entity') AS nodes(entity)
```

Basically, convert the value of `field3` to a string, if it's NULL, use 0.00 as the DECIMAL value instead.

I don't know if there's any way with the `OPENXML` approach to do something similar...

Comment: I was informed in another thread that performance would be worse... but I may have to try if I can't find another solution.

Comment: Performance was bad for thousands of records, but it gave me an idea and I truly appreciate your help as I would not have gotten the idea without seeing your code.  In addition, I think your solution is fine for smaller sets of data (and/or faster servers).

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it would be to use the `/text()` function:

```
DECLARE @importData XML;
DECLARE @myTable TABLE
(
  field1 INT,
  field2 VARCHAR(40),
  field3 DECIMAL(15,2)
);

SET @importData =
'<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Entities>
  <Entity>
  <field1>2435</field1>
  <field2>843257-3242</field2>
  <field3 />
  </Entity>
</Entities>
';

INSERT INTO @myTable
(
  [field1],
  [field2],
  [field3]
)
SELECT
  t.tmp.value('(./field1)[1]', 'INT') AS field1,
  t.tmp.value('(./field2)[1]', 'VARCHAR(40)') AS field2,
  t.tmp.value('(./field3/text())[1]', 'DECIMAL(15,2)') AS field3
FROM
  @importData.nodes('//Entity') AS t(tmp);

SELECT * FROM @myTable;
```

Will result in:

```
field1 | field2      | field3
-----------------------------
2435   | 843257-3242 | NULL
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution because the node is text anyways and you are tricking sql server to give you a null and if is not null then it works as it would work normally.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I would not have tried this but marc_s put me on the right track so I will give him credit for the answer.

I tried XQuery as suggested by Marc, but performance was miserable for the quantity of records I was dealing with.  But I used a similar technique in my original code...

```
EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @l_index OUTPUT, @importData
INSERT INTO dbo.myTable
(
     [field1]
    ,[field2]
    ,CASE
       WHEN [field3] = '' THEN NULL
       ELSE CAST([wl_llr] AS DECIMAL(15,2)) -- CHANGED TO CASE
     END
)
SELECT
     [field1]
    ,[field2]
    ,[field3]
FROM OPENXML(@l_index, 'Entities/Entity', 1)
    WITH 
    (
         field1 int 'field1'
        ,field2 varchar(40) 'field2'
        ,field3 varchar(50) 'field3' -- CHANGED TO VARCHAR
    )
EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @l_index
```

Comment: If this is the right answer then mark it as such. I understand wanting to give marc_s credit for helping, but it makes it more difficult for people to see what worked. Plus, I don't think marc is sweating the points... ;)

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution would be to create a secondary field in your target table that accepts a string value.  After populating the table with the XML data, execute a statement to update your integer field, setting it to NULL when the string field is blank.

For example, here is my XML string.

```
'<xml>
    <d MetricID="1" Days="15" Sort="1" />
    <d MetricID="2" Days="45" Sort="2" />
    <d MetricID="3" Days="29" Sort="3" />
    <d MetricID="4" Days="119" Sort="4" />
    <d MetricID="5" Days="59" Sort="5" />
    <d MetricID="6" Days="179" Sort="6" />
    <d MetricID="7" Days="0" Sort="7" />
    <d MetricID="8" Days="" Sort="8" />
    <d MetricID="9" Days="60" Sort="9" />
</xml>'
```

Nodes 7 and 8 have respective Days values of 0 and Blank.  Zero needs to be preserved, and blank needs to be saved as NULL.  Here was my solution for achieving this.

```
DECLARE @idoc INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @xmlDeadline
CREATE TABLE #Deadline
(       TimeframeMetricID INT
        , DeadlineDays INT NULL
        , DaysString VARCHAR(5) -- Hack for identifying DeadlineDays that were blank (null).
        , SortOrder INT
)

INSERT INTO #Deadline
        (TimeframeMetricID
       , DeadlineDays
       , DaysString
       , SortOrder
        )
SELECT  MetricID
        , Days
        , DaysString
        , Sort
FROM    OPENXML
(       @iDoc           -- Handle to the XML doc.
        , 'xml/d'       -- Map to the node that contains the attributes.
        , 1             --  Attribute centric mapping (1), instead of Element centric mapping (2).
)
WITH
(       MetricID INT '@MetricID'    -- Select attribute.  When selecting element remove @ sign.
        , Days  INT '@Days'
        , DaysString VARCHAR(5) '@Days' -- Hack for identifying DeadlineDays that were blank (null).
        , Sort  INT '@Sort'

) a

-- Release the XML parser
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @idoc

-- Now convert Days that arrived as blank (i.e. Days="") from zero to NULL
-- to accurately reflect the supplied values.
UPDATE  #Deadline
SET     DeadlineDays = NULL
WHERE   (DaysString = '')

SELECT * FROM #Deadline
```

To recap what's happening above.  The code grabs the Days attribute twice. Put one in an INT column and one in a VARCHAR column.  After the XML INSERT statement occurs, run an UPDATE statement to convert the targeted INT field to NULL when it's related VARCHAR column is blank.

This approach *may* offer better performance than XQuery.  I'll leave that to someone else on this thread.